# Force TinyMCE to keep the original source code format

Tags: php, html, tinymce, wysiwyg

I have a database, where several pages are stored from a CMS system. The pages have **HTML**, **JavaScript** and several **PHP** calls. In general the code looks like this (only a bit longer):

```
<div style="width:603px;height:446px;position:relative;">
    <div style="position:absolute;width:567px;border-bottom:1px solid rgb(200,200,200);">
        SOME TEXT GOES HERE
    </div>
    <?php somePhpCall(); ?>
    <script>hoverImages()</script>
</div>
```

What I need is a WYSIWYG editor, that allows me to modify that code and keep the elements in tact. TinyMCE makes the formatting like this:

```
<p>SOME TEXT GOES HERE</p>
```

and loses all CSS, JS and PHP code.

Can I configure **TinyMCE** to keep the original source code format and if not - what alternative WYSIWYG editor can I use.

**P.S**: I've downloaded the latest version and it keeps changing my `<?php` tags to `<!--?php` or `&lt;?php` and my `<script>` tags to `<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[`.
I've tried using `apply_source_formatting : true`

Thank you.

Comment: what about using html_encodeentitties() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you TinyMCE config only java script used. another WYSIWYG editor url link integrate your program  automatically config  WYSIWYG editor
example code

```
    <script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution for this issue by using the portect option:

```
tinymce.init({
    protect: [
        /\<\/?(if|endif)\>/g, // Protect <if> & </endif>
        /\<xsl\:[^>]+\>/g, // Protect <xsl:...>
        /<\?php.*?\?>/g // Protect php code
    ]
});
```

Comment: You should likely reference the docs where you find the code snippet you used for an answer, it does provide some context: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/Configuration3x/Configuration3x@protect/

Answer (score -1):

You should read this part of the 
**TinyMCE Documentation** : http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:Cleanup/Output

Comment: The link is not valid.